# Ошибка discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я создаю своего дискорд-бота, всё работало. После этого, в течении некоторого времени, я был занят и не трогал его. Сегодня решил его доделать, запускаю, а тут ошибки:

[2022-09-23 21:37:04] [WARNING ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.

[2022-09-23 21:37:04] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token

[2022-09-23 21:37:06] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID:).

Я даже создал ещё одного бота и написал мини программку, но она вызывала ту же ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста:
https://pastebin.com/v5ukjVxV - та мини-программка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord обновился, добавлены intents, вы должны перейти в портал разработчика и в своем боте разрешить intents, и добавить в код своего бота следующие строчки :

````
intents = discord.Intents.default().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="ваш префикс", intents=intents)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Это не ошибка, а новая версия discord py. Что касается WARNING - это решается так:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)
```